# Fill/seal large gap around shower base

Tags: shower, plaster, sealing, silicone, sealant

We just bought a new house and I noticed the shower is leaking. I went to reseal the shower with a silicon based sealant, but then noticed that the gaps are pretty large.

Along one side, between shower base and wall tiles the gap is variable between about 12mm to 5mm. This gap was previously filled with a decent portion of plaster (possibly plaster board) and then sealed at the top/bottom.

Also, the shower door, frame should sit on top of the shower tray edge, but instead there is a gap of between 10-15mm. Again, they had filled the majority of the gap with plaster and then sealed top and bottom with silicon.

Overtime, the plaster on both gaps has obviously just dried out, cracked and moved and the sealant has just come away.

I couldn't believe this is the correct way to do it, so I have removed all the plaster. Or was I a bit hasty and is this a reasonable way to deal with it.

What other methods can I used to fill much a big gap (upto 15mm).

Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to say without a piccie (hint), but it *sounds* like it would suit a thin row of tiles, grouted as normal, then (when dry) seal the (now smaller) gap between the new tile row and the shower base. You can silicon larger gaps (within reason) and I have in the past where no other option is viable. Just silicon the most you can get away with, then let it cure, then silicon again from the new cured silicon as a base to work from. Latter is not ideal though, and tends to look cheap/bodged.

Comment: I refilled the big whole with filler, let it dry and then resealed the edges with silicon. Can't think of anything better to do, seems to be holding for now though.